# Non clickable background with AngularJS loading bar

Tags: css, angularjs

I am trying to set non-clickable loading bar and everything looks good but I can still click on the button. You can see the same on plnkr.

https://plnkr.co/edit/4eh6ibG45JnLB6qYktxn?p=preview

I checked that both of the bellow div has attribute "pointer-events: none" but its not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-loading-bar/0.9.0/loading-bar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>

        #loading-bar {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            z-index: 11002;

        }

        #loading-bar-spinner {
            display: block;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 11002; 
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -15px;
            margin-right: -15px;

        }
    </style>

    <div ng-app="LoadingBarExample" ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
        <button ng-click="startLoading()">startLoading</button>
        <button ng-click="completeLoading()">completeLoading</button>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-loading-bar/0.9.0/loading-bar.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var LoadingBarExample = angular.module('LoadingBarExample', ['chieffancypants.loadingBar', 'ngAnimate'])
            .config(function (cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
                //cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeSpinner = false;
                //cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeBar = false;
                //    //cfpLoadingBarProvider.spinnerTemplate = '<div><span class="fa fa-spinner">Loading...</div>';

                //    //cfpLoadingBarProvider.parentSelector = '#loading-bar-container';
                //    //cfpLoadingBarProvider.spinnerTemplate = '<div><span class="fa fa-spinner">Custom Loading Message...</div>';


            });
        LoadingBarExample.controller('ExampleCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, cfpLoadingBar) {
            $scope.startLoading = function () {
                cfpLoadingBar.start();
            };
            $scope.completeLoading = function () {
                cfpLoadingBar.complete();
            };

        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**loading-bar**
[image]
**loading-bar-spinner**
[image]

Comment: why do you need `pointer-events: none` on the *loaders*? there are no events on it, you can remove it and the buttons will no longer be clickable...

Comment: Why can't you hide them, with css just add a class when loading.

Comment: @kukkuz thanks I updated css class with pointer-events:auto; and that worked. Also updated in plnkr.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this with angularjs way, just add `ng-disabled="loading"` to make the button disabled and enabled based on the loading value

```
   <button ng-disabled="loading" ng-click="startLoading()">startLoading</button>
   <button ng-disabled="loading" ng-click="completeLoading()">completeLoading</button>
```

and controller as,

```
 LoadingBarExample.controller('ExampleCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, cfpLoadingBar) {
             $scope.loading = false;
            $scope.startLoading = function () {
                cfpLoadingBar.start();
                 $scope.loading =true;

            };
            $scope.completeLoading = function () {
                cfpLoadingBar.complete();
                  $scope.loading =false;
            };

        });
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/dCJ1FaJca2bkri1Jwxbn)**

**EDIT**

If you want to disable the whole form with a single way, use fieldset instead of div and use ng-disabled

```
  <fieldset ng-disabled="loading" ng-app="LoadingBarExample" ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
        <button  ng-click="startLoading()">startLoading</button>
        <button  ng-click="completeLoading()">completeLoading</button>
  </fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks but if we have more controls this solution will be difficult implement. I would like to do this with the help of css.

Comment: This is better but I am looking for CSS option.

Comment: ok here is the solution with css https://plnkr.co/edit/UlOjwNUHPSsTUHHbe49R

Comment: Thanks. I got CSS solution and updated in plnkr as well.